# ¿ Es correcto decir "disparada por su cuñado"?

Tags: traducción, inglés

Desde hace unos años vengo notando el uso del participio pasivo del verbo [disparar](https://dle.rae.es/?w=disparar) con el significado de ser `el receptor de un tiro`, como por ejemplo [aquí](https://www.20minutos.es/noticia/4066971/0/quien-es-nadia-otmani-mujer-enfrento-ortega-smith/#https://www.20minutos.es/noticia/4066864/0/reproches-nadia-otmani-ortega-smith-vox-respeto-muertas-victimas-violencia-genero/), donde aparece la expresión "**disparada por su cuñado**".

A mi modo de ver, creo que **no es correcto** ya que ninguno de los significados que indica la [RAE](https://dle.rae.es/?w=disparar) se acerca a "recibir un tiro".

¿Es entonces una mala traducción al español del verbo inglés **`to shoot`**, el cual, según se indica [aquí](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shoot), sí admite el significado de recibir un disparo (*to fire a bullet or an arrow, **or to hit, injure, or kill a person or animal by firing a bullet or arrow at him, her, or it***) ?

Saludos

Comment: Claro, recibir un tiro, no es disparar. shoot tampoco es "recibir un disparo"; shoot es disparar. He was shot [pasado] by his cousin. = Fue herido por una bala disparada por su primo. to be shot=ser herido por una bala– Lambie 5 mins ago   Edit   Delete

Comment: O fue herido por un disparo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es muy probable que expresiones como ❌ *”Alicia fue disparada por su cuñado”*, que quieren transmitir la idea de que "A Alicia le disparó su cuñado", "Alicia recibió un disparo de su cuñado", sean efectivamente calcos del inglés.

En la voz pasiva en castellano, el objeto directo de un verbo transitivo es promovido a sujeto:

> *Su cuñado disparó **un arma**<sub>(OD)</sub>.* → ***Un arma***<sub>(suj)</sub> fue disparada por su cuñado.

En inglés la voz pasiva funciona de la misma manera, pero también se permite promover el objeto indirecto:

> *Her brother-in-law shot **her**<sub>(OI)</sub>.* → ***She***<sub>(suj)</sub> was shot by her brother-in-law.

En el caso de *shoot* quizá no se perciba la diferencia porque este verbo sólo permite un objeto, directo o indirecto, pero no los dos, y no hay manera de diferenciarlos. Con otro verbo se observa más claramente:

> *The policeman asked him a question.*

(donde *him* es el objeto indirecto y *a question* es el objeto directo). De esta oración se pueden formar dos pasivas, promoviendo uno o el otro:

> OD: *A question was posed to him by the policeman.*
>   OI: *He was asked a question by the policeman.*

Y de hecho yo he leído malas traducciones del segundo caso, del tipo

> ❌ *Él fue preguntado por el policía.*

De manera que no es que el verbo *disparar* sea incorrecto en esta clase de estructura; es que la estructura misma de esta voz pasiva está mal, ya que intenta promover a sujeto un objeto indirecto (de hecho, una de las pruebas diagnósticas para diferenciar un OD de un OI es probar si se lo puede promover a sujeto usando voz pasiva).

Comment: No hay que confundir **en inglés**, to be shot by someone cuando quiere decir  **ser herido por bala** y **disparar a alguien** to shoot (at) someone.

Comment: @Lambie - And related to your comment, there's also "to be shot at by someone."

Comment: Pablo, me encanta el símbolo X.  ¿Qué te dio la idea, y dónde lo encontraste? // Re my edit -- I think I found a source: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07HQ919WR/ref=dp-kindle-redirect?_encoding=UTF8&btkr=1, p. 227.

Comment: @aparente001 Yes, that is already covered. ser disparado por alguien, el opuesto de disparar a alguien..

Comment: @Lambie - If you think "ser disparado por alguien" works, I hope you'll write an answer.  I'd be interested to see this idea developed.

Comment: @aparente001 If disparar al alguien works so does ser disparado por alguien. I have addressed all the issues. There is nothing more for me to develop beyond my initial comment. I don't much like giving answers for translation into Spanish for basic misunderstandings. It requires teaching some translation principles.

Comment: @Lambie In "disparar a alguien", "a alguien" is the indirect, not the direct object, and in Spanish it cannot be the subject of the passive, as explained by pablodf76. Proof that "a alguien" is IO and not DO is that it can be substituted for by "le", not "lo" or "la": *Su cuñado LE disparó* (He shot (at) her). "la disparó" would refer to the weapon, not the person getting shot.

Comment: Of course you can say *"Ella fue disparada por su cuñado"*, but it would only make sense if she was a circus human cannonball and her brother-in-law was in charging of firing the cannon.

Comment: Yes, I immediately thought of the circus performer getting shot out of the cannon too when I read the comment from Gustavson! // @Lambie, I do encourage you to develop your point of view in an answer.  Comments are ephemeral.  Your point of view seems different from what Pablo wrote.  I'd like to understand your view better, and an answer is the best place to do that.

Comment: Pablo is right. Here, in the Panhispánico dictionary one can find the same that was stated by him: http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=disparar